# Parse Static Google Transit Data?

Tags: swift

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I could parse this static google transit data (in swift)?

http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/subway/google_transit.zip

It provides a data for a bunch of the NYC Subway lines that aren't yet tracked in real time, however, I am having difficulty seeing how I'd be process this data (as in, incrementing through the arrivals of each train at a station)

Any recommendations?

Comment: The format is GTFS, it's described [here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) and it's similar to CSV. I'd try using a third-party CSV library.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate behavior similar to this, where given a stop and the present time, it returns the trains leaving the station https://github.com/google/transitfeed/wiki/ScheduleViewer